# RemoteApp Custom image + o365. Outlook cant find account

Tags: azure

I have deployed a custom RemoteApp image with applications + office 365.

When i start Outlook, i get the error:
We are having trouble connecting to your account. Verify the settings below and make changes if necessary.

Other Office applications work perfectly (including getting the o365 licence).

How can i fix the error, and have users log into Outlook straight Away?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your Azure environment did not pickup the autodiscover added to your domain. So please check your internal DNS record for autodiscover.

Comment: Now it works. I appreciate your help